# Jetpack Compose thumb image

Tags: android, kotlin, slider, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

What would be the best way to change the Compose Slider thumb image. Now it is possible to change the color but not an image?
I was thinking to use a Box() with a Slider and Image on top but not sure how to implement it

Comment: I don't think Slider can do this, because Compose is implemented by default according to Material Design, and I don't think Slider can be replaced with an image in the MD concept.

Comment: Not by default. Would need to make a custom Slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the library below that allowed me to set an Image

https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Colorful-Sliders

Answer (score 2):

With **M3** `androidx.compose.material3.Slider` you can use the **`thumb`** attribute to use a custom thumb.

For example you can use an `Image`,something like:

```
var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
Column {
    Text(text = sliderPosition.toString())
    Slider(
        modifier = Modifier.semantics { contentDescription = "Localized Description" },
        value = sliderPosition,
        onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it },
        valueRange = 0f..5f,
        steps = 4,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        onValueChangeFinished = {
            // launch some business logic update with the state you hold
        },
        thumb = {
            Image(painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),"contentDescription")
        }

    )
}
```

[image]

or a simple `Icon`:

```
var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
Column {
    Text(text = sliderPosition.toString())
    Slider(
        modifier = Modifier.semantics { contentDescription = "Localized Description" },
        value = sliderPosition,
        onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it },
        valueRange = 0f..5f,
        steps = 4,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        onValueChangeFinished = {
            // launch some business logic update with the state you hold
        },
        thumb = {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.Favorite,
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.size(ButtonDefaults.IconSize),
                tint = Color.Red
            )
        }

    )
}
```

[image]

**Note:** it requires for `material3` at least the version `1.0.0-beta03`

Comment: Just want to mention that this is included in a stable release of Material3 now, `1.1.0`, though the API itself is still marked as experimental. This was a lifesaver, thanks!